# 500 error when updating a Database entry

Tags: php, database, laravel, postman

I am currently building an api within my laravel project and I am getting a 500 error when running the request through postman, everything seems to be fine within my update method. can anyone help me figure out what I am missing?

```
 public function update(Request $request, Status $status)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'server' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            $response = array('response' => $validator->messages(), 'success' => false);
            return $response;
        } else {
            $statusStore = Status::find($status);
            $statusStore->server = $request->input('server');
            $statusStore->status = $request->input('status');
            $statusStore->save();

            return response()->json($statusStore);
        }
    }
```

[screenshot of postman inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYwsD.png)

Comment: Have you looked at your server error log? Does Laravel have error logs of its own?

Comment: @GregSchmidt it does but all the errors located in that log are routing errors I had previously

Comment: Apache logs? error_log? A 500 error is almost certainly being logged somewhere.